# CSS expand div and add scrollbars

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I implemented tree rendering based on this excellent tutorial:

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree

But for large trees, it seems that entire subtrees are "wrapped" around like text, which splits the tree into a confusing mess.

See the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/shkAh/

Any ideas how to automatically expand the canvas and add scrollbars? I tried with various permutations of overflow:auto, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify how wide you want the tree to be.
Try putting something like this in the CSS:
`div.tree { width: 2000px; }`

Comment: Yes, that sort of works. But then I get a scrollbar that covers a huge white area for most scenarios. I would prefer if the div could somehow be auto-expanded as needed.

Comment: OK. Maybe this will work? `div.tree { white-space: nowrap; }`